# linker error: ld: library not found for -lAppLovinSdk

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, cocos2d-x, applovin

I am trying to build lite version of my cocos2dx Iphone game using Applovin. I followed the guidelines here https://github.com/wenbin1989/applovin-x

But when I build the lite version of the app, I get a linker error

ld: library not found for -lAppLovinSdk
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure "AppLovinSdk.a" is there in your project folder. Please try adding "AppLovinSdk.a" in "Target -> Build Phases -> Link With Libraries"? Also if not working add path to "AppLovinSdk" to "Library Search Paths" under Build Settings.

Comment: I have already added it http://tinypic.com/r/10x5a0y/8

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Xcode not able to trace the library at a defined path. Please follow below mentioned steps:

Go to "Build Settings" -> Library Search Path and check whether the desired lib file path is present there? And if present then is it correct?

Also check the Header Search Path for the same lib.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with AppLovin specifically, but it does mean that Xcode can't find the library. If you haven't already, try removing and re-adding the file to your project. Cleaning the build folder may also help.

Comment: how can I clean the build folder ?, where is it located ?

Answer (score 0):

As you clean your project using Command+Shift+K, You just need to press Command+Option+Shift+K to clean your build folder.

Enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

Perform this steps:

- Close all Xcode Projects. (`.xcworkspace` and `.xcproject`);
- Run `pod install` and `pod update`;
- Open the `.xcworkspace`;
- Clean and Build your Project;
- You should be able to run normally.